# XPath for dynamic table

Tags: xpath

In the application I have to click red cross mark to delete. I have attached image[Image showing Delete icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oni7x.jpg). I need an xpath to click red cross icon.

I tried following xpath but it does not work :

```
//div[contains(text(),'UG_AUTOMATION')]*/i[@class='x-fa fa-icon-red fa-times-circle']
```

Below is the html tag

```
<td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1089 x-grid-cell-first x-unselectable" style="width: 485px;" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-1089" xpath="1"><div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;">UG_AUTOMATION</div></td>
<td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-actioncolumn-1090 x-action-col-cell x-grid-cell-last x-unselectable" data-qtip="Delete" style="width:50px;" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="actioncolumn-1090" xpath="1"><div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner x-grid-cell-inner-action-col" style="text-align:center;"><span class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><i class="x-fa fa-icon-red fa-times-circle"></i></span><div tabindex="-1" role="button" class="x-action-col-icon x-action-col-0  " data-tabindex-value="0" data-tabindex-counter="1"></div></div></td>
```

Comment: Do not include code as image. Include it as text in a `code` section instead.

Comment: Add HTML code as text

Comment: I do not know what you intend to mean by this comment. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62284190/edit) your question to include the HTML code in a `code` section and remove the image link.

Comment: I have added application image with html code. I need to find xpath to click on red cross mark.

Comment: Can you explain in which application you work ? What will you delete ? I don't understand your question ! I think that you must absolutely improve it giving some code.

Comment: I have attached application image where I want to delete a row with value UG AUTOMATION. To delete I need to click red cross button. I have added html code in code section.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Python, you could use the following XPath (we use `following` axis) :

```
//div[contains(text(),'UG_AUTOMATION')]/following::i[@class='x-fa fa-icon-red fa-times-circle']
```

Piece of code with required imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element= WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(),'UG_AUTOMATION')]/following::i[@class='x-fa fa-icon-red fa-times-circle']"))).click()
```

Alternative element to click on :

```
//div[contains(text(),'UG_AUTOMATION')]/following::span[@class="btn btn-default btn-sm"]
```

If you need to click on the `div` element containing the icon, you have to remove its attribute :

```
element= WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(),'UG_AUTOMATION')]/following::div[1]")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('unselectable')", element)
element.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

To select the second `<td>` element (from where you can choose any child you want), you can use this XPath-1.0 expression:

```
//td[contains(div/text(),'UG_AUTOMATION')]/following-sibling::td[div/span/i/@class='x-fa fa-icon-red fa-times-circle']/@data-qtip
```

The last part `/@data-qtip` is only there to get an output (here it is `Delete`). Replace it as you desire.